# EVM Balance reset

Tags: evm

I am using EVM.
I open the wallet, perform the transfer and lock the wallet again.

I have no problems with the transfer. However, after a while, I see that the remaining wallet balance is automatically reset. The remaining balance is automatically sent to the fee wallet after a while. How can I prevent this?

Log:
INFO [06-17|22:01:08.458] Submitted transaction                    hash=0x26cdd5b36dd76c546eccc03ff466d03ecf3e8a8581aa831282fa2cf433c39a8c from=0xD47d20c64Dc9599C4454114676cb114bf4BE4F81 nonce=47   recipient=0x071aAd74A52f76aeC4a4b4fecfc910dbC8fe03F4 value=2,989,500,000,000,000,000

Comment: Is your account compromised? Then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYkyAi9b9r8) video might help. What chain are you on?